# Add a counter to a function

Tags: php, function

I've got this bubble sort function, and I'd like to add a counter to the swap function. So basically, I'd like to know how many times it swapped numbers in the array to sort it from low > high.

```
<?php

function bubble_sort($arr) {
$size = count($arr);
for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {
        if ($arr[$j+1] < $arr[$j]) {
            swap($arr, $j, $j+1);
        }
    }
}
return $arr;
}

function swap(&$arr, $a, $b){
$tmp = $arr[$a];
$arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
$arr[$b] = $tmp;
}


$arr = array(81,4,12,-1,99,100,-10);

echo("Voor bubble sort<br>");
print_r($arr);

$arr = bubble_sort($arr);
echo("<br>Na bubble sort<br>");
print_r($arr);

?>
```

I tried adding a counter++ in the swap function, but this is giving me errors.

Comment: Hint #1: IIFE and closure

Answer (score 0):

You can not do counter++ on a variable that isn't initialized yet. It needs to be set to 0 before calling the swap function. You could also pass $count each time to the function or use a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small class, is that waht you are looking for?

```
class bubble {

    public $counter = array();
    public $arr = null;

    public function __construct($arr){
        $this->arr = $arr;
    }

    public function sort(){
        $size = count($this->arr);

        for ($i=0; $i<$size; $i++) {

            for ($j=0; $j<$size-1-$i; $j++) {

                if ($this->arr[$j+1] < $this->arr[$j]) {
                    $this->swap($this->arr, $j, $j+1);
                }

            }
        }

    }

    function swap(&$arr, $a, $b){
        $tmp = $arr[$a];
        $this->arr[$a] = $arr[$b];
        $this->arr[$b] = $tmp;
        $this->counter[$a]++;
    }
}

$arr = array(81,4,12,-1,99,100,-10);
$bubble = new bubble($arr);

echo("Voor bubble sort<br>");
print_r($bubble->arr);

$bubble->sort();
echo("<br>Na bubble sort<br>");
print_r($bubble->arr);

echo("<br>Swap counter (by key)<br>");
print_r($bubble->counter);
```

Demo: https://eval.in/201077